# str_replace in file names

Tags: php, file, directory, str-replace

I have a PHP code that displays the file contents of a directory in a list. Each file is linked so that if clicked, it will download or open. The files inside the directory will be files uploaded by customers. If the file name contains spaces, the link is broken and will not open, so I would like to have the spaces replaced with underscores.

I know that str_replace does what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this code (which I did not write).

```
// Define the full path to your folder from root 
$path = "uploads/artwork"; 


// Open the folder 
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 

if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 

    continue; 
    echo "<a href=uploads/artwork/$file>$file</a><br />"; 

} 
// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to replace the filenames with underscores when you save them to the server, also.

Since you don't have the code on where you save the files, you can [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) the link URL so it will not be broken by hazardous characters. Note that originally it was broken by spaces because you didn't have the `href` value enclosed in quotes, which I'm doing here:

```
echo "<a href='" . urlencode("uploads/artwork/$file") . "'>$file</a><br />";
```

Otherwise, to replace spaces with underscores, you'd do:

```
echo "<a href=" . str_replace( ' ', "_", "uploads/artwork/$file") . ">$file</a><br />";
```

But again, that would likely require you changing the file names on upload.

Note that you'll also want to call [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) on the `$file` portion of that link, to prevent characters such as `<` from breaking the HTML page. So, the final result would be:

```
echo "<a href='" . urlencode("uploads/artwork/$file") . "'>" . htmlentities( $file) . "</a><br />";
```